# My wireless in HP P001TX is not working

Tags: wireless

My WiFi is not working. I am using HP p001TX laptop with Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 bgn wifi adapter. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: @Pilot6 for you =)

Comment: please someone help me.Please  help me

Comment: Common, please give us some more time … ;)

Comment: Do you have a wired internet connection?

Comment: No sir I have not any wired connection.sir I can no access the internet so I am not download & install any packages.Please sir help me

Comment: Look at the previous comment. There is a link how  to fix it.

Comment: For 12.04 it should also work.

Comment: If you won't be able to get the broadcom card working,  then get yourself a usb dongle with rtl8191 chipset. Works out of the box,  no driver install necessary

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to find somewhere a cable connection and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: sir one more question. I have an  XXXX.tar.bz2 file.how to install it in my system?pls help me sir

Comment: @EkPoshlaBristi: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I have an XXXX.tar.bz2 file.how to install it in my system?pls help me sir

Comment: @EkPoshlaBristi Please ask a separate question for a different matter.

Comment: sir I am not able to post my question.why??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: i am using the app stack exchange.it is showing an error message